# Mimicking react-router-dom Nested Routes in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jamstack

I am trying to mimic [this example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting) from react-router. I dug through some issues on GH and it doesn't seem possible. At the same time, though, isn't this something that is basic/common among web apps? Am I missing something obvious?

My current structure is:

```
/pages
  /session
    [sid].js
    /topics
      [tid].js
```

The session page has a list of topics that I want to update *on the `[sid].js`* page. However, everything I tried just navigates to `[tid].js`. I've tried using `<Link>` with replace but this doesn't do what I want because I do still want the item in history. I tried `router.push` but I'm in the same boat and would really like to use a `<a>` element.

Comment: Are you using `react-router` in `Next.js`?

Comment: No. I'm using next/router.

Comment: Could you show me parts of your code?